# Как отцентрировать изображение по вертикали?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отцентрировать изображение `.image_window_img` по вертикали с учетом того, что высота его может быть разной? Благодарю!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".image").click(function(){
        var img = $(this);
        var src = img.attr('src');
        $("body").append("<div class='image_window'>"+"<div class='image_window_bg'></div>"+"<img src="+src+" class='image_window_img' />"+"<div class='image_window_close'></div>"+"</div>"); 
        $(".image_window").fadeIn(800);
        $(".image_window_bg,.image_window_close").click(function(){    
            $(".image_window").fadeOut(800);
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(".image_window").remove();
            }, 800);
        });
    });
}); 
.image_window {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.image_window_bg {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.image_window_img {
    z-index: 101;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 99%;
    max-width: 99%;
    margin: 1% 0 0 0;
}
                <img src="" class="image">
                <img src="" class="image">
```

Comment: Ответ зависит от многих факторов. В частности от `css` окружающих элементов. Приведите минимальный пример с `css`.

Comment: Почему игнорируешь ответы Оо

Comment: Уже не актуально, но вы просто проигнорировали мой ответ:)

Comment: В моем примере не учитываются размеры картинки, так как вы задаёте их сам, это нормальная практика, и если вы посмотрите на известные сайты многие используют это решение, но пусть будет по вашему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться вот таким способом. Только с помощью `css` и этот способ универсальный.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tz9nkyx1/).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.image_window {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.image_window_bg {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.image_window_img {
  z-index: 101;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='image_window'>
  <div class='image_window_bg'></div>
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class='image_window_img' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

`html`:

```
<div class='img-container'>
        <img class='image_window_img'  src='https://pp.userapi.com/c629327/v629327473/db67/M2FQtImGf7k.jpg'>
        <img class='image_window_img'  src='https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg'>
        <img class='image_window_img'  src='http://elt-group.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/boj-betona-%D1%88%D1%8C%D0%BF.jpg'>
        <img class='image_window_img'  src='https://pp.userapi.com/c629327/v629327473/db67/M2FQtImGf7k.jpg'>
</div>
```

`css`:

```
.img-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
} 

.image_window_img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px; 
}
```

Пример: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dtsqpt2r/)